# jQuery draggable helper is not draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have  a draggable item with a class of '.item', once i drag it to its destination it just sits there and i can't move it around, this is the code i'm using :

```
        $('.item').draggable({
            helper : 'clone',
            onStartDrag:function(){
                $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                $(this).draggable('clone').css('z-index',10);
            },
            onStopDrag:function(){
                $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
            }
        });

        $('.cart').droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                $.ui.ddmanager.current.cancelHelperRemoval = true;
            },
            onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
            },
            onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                $.ui.ddmanager.current.cancelHelperRemoval = false;
            },
            onDrop:function(e,source){
                var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revised Drop function in Dropppable method

```
 $(".item").draggable({
    helper:'clone',
    onStartDrag:function(){
            $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
            $(this).draggable('clone').css('z-index',10);
        },
        onStopDrag:function(){
            $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
        }
});  

$(".cart").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    drop: function(event,ui){
        var new_signature = $(ui.helper).clone().removeClass('item');
        new_signature.draggable();
        $(this).append(new_signature);
    },
     onDragEnter:function(e,source){
            $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
        },
        onDragLeave:function(e,source){
            $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
            $.ui.ddmanager.current.cancelHelperRemoval = false;
        },
        onDrop:function(e,source){
            var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
            var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
            addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
        }
});
```

Comment: But the purpose of the helper is to make a copy of the item, not to drag the original item.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Yasemin but now the item doesn't even fall on the cart class, i can drag it but when i dropped it, it just disappears.

Comment: can you share html file

Comment: Thank you, you're a life saver.

Comment: it does not matter.Can you answer up